# Does the ranger's UA Primal Awareness variant class feature allow you to cast each spell once per long rest, or only one of them?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, unearthed-arcana, spellcasting

The [Unearthed Arcana - Class Feature Variants](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf) article introduces [*Primal Awareness*](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-ClassFeatures.pdf#page=8), a new variant feature for the ranger that replaces the original 3rd-level feature, *Primeval Awareness*.

This feature lists a number spells as additional spells known that don't count against the number of ranger spells you know. That part of the feature is fairly clear. However, it goes on to say:

> You can cast each of these spells once without expending a spell slot. Once you cast a spell in this way, you can't do so again until you finish a long rest.

To me, this section is unclear and has two possible interpretations:

1. *"You can cast **each** of these spells once..."* - You can cast each of the spells lists 1/long rest without expending a spell slot. A total of 6 spells cast per day.
2. You can cast **any** of these spells once. - Once you have cast one of these spells in this way, you cannot cast any of them until you finish a long rest. A total of 1 spell cast per day.

I can make a logical argument for both cases, one based on the first sentence, the other on the second.

**Which of these interpretations is correct?**

Comment: I assume you're asking about a case in which the ranger is high-level enough to have access to all of them (or more than one of them, at least).

Comment: Related: [How many spells can a triton cast per long rest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97674/how-many-spells-can-a-triton-cast-per-long-rest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The first interpretation is correct

Taking this a line at a time

> You can cast **each** of these spells once without expending a spell slot.

**Each** is the key word here, and clearly refers to every spell being different

> Once you cast **a** spell in this way, you can't do so again until you finish a long rest.

**A** is the key word in this line, and the object being referenced has already been identified in the line earlier, so it refers to every spell individually.

**In summary:**

You can cast each of the spells 1/long rest without using a spell slot. A total of 6 spells per day.

**Note:**

As with all UA content, this is still pending feedback, so while I think my interpretation is correct based on the current wording there is scope in terms of balance for the opposite interpretation; I just don't see support for it within the wording.

Answer (score 7):

### You can cast each of the spells in the list once.

As you said in option one in your question, the text reads "*You can cast each of these spells once...*"; implying that you can cast each of the individual spells listed in the table above it once (refreshing after a long rest).

Comment: I believe the question revolves around the second part of the ability, "Once you cast **a** spell in this way, you can't do so again until you finish a long rest."
This can be worded as "Once you cast a spell in this way, you can't cast another spell in this way until you finish a long rest" suggesting the reading of one spell total per rest. If the first case were true that you can cast each once, there would be no need of the second sentence talking about once you have cast - it would have just read "You can cast each of these spells once per long rest."

Comment: I think while your answer is sort of correct, it doesn't fully address the question in that sense. You can cast them unlimited times up to your spell slots, plus one extra time without using a spell slot.
I think the rules are meant to read in the vein of "When you cast these spells without spending a spell slot, you must expend a spell slot to cast that spell again until you long rest."